# Rails multiply joined columns with foreign key null

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these tables:

```
STOCKDIARY

- ID, DATE, PRODUCT, UNITS, PRICE

PRODUCTS

- ID, NAME, CONSIGNOR

CONSIGNORS

- ID, NAME, COMMISSION
```

I have setup all associations. So that if in my view I use:

```
stockdiary.product.consignor.try(:COMMISSION)
```

I get the right commission for each product in a stockdiary line.

Note that I use `try` because not all products have a consignor.

But now I need to show `stockdiary.PRICE * stockdiary.product.consignor.COMMISSION`

So in Stockdiary model I set

```
def total_commission
  (self.PRICE * self.product.consignor.COMMISSION)
end
```

But this gives me an error: 
`undefined method 'COMMISSION' for nil:NilClass`

I think the problem comes from the fact that some product has empty value in CONSIGNOR column. Just to make sure I have entered a value for each row on table CONSIGNORS column COMMISSION. But error is still there.

I would like stockdiaries row with products without a consignor to show 0 as commission.

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method1:**

Give the try column to  `consignor` instead of `COMMISSION` or give for both.

```
def total_commission
    (self.PRICE * self.try(:product).try(:consignor).try(:COMMISSION))
end
```

**Method2:**

Also you can use,

```
def total_commission
    consignor = self.product.consignor.present? ?  self.product.consignor.COMMISSION : 0
    (self.PRICE * consignor)
end
```

what it does is, if there is consignor, it takes it else it takes 0 as you mentioned.

Comment: @catmal, try the second approach, its the more rails way

Comment: The second approach returns Location(#69853755169400) expected, got Fixnum(#47292841845800)

Comment: I voted it. But honestly I don't have the knowledge to judge which of the 3 approaches is best.. So I accepted the first one..

Answer (score 2):

As you said before:

> Note that I use `try` because not all products have a consignor.

So you need:

```
def total_commission
  commission = self.product&.consignor&.COMMISSION
  if self.PRICE && commission
     (self.PRICE * commission)
  else
      nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def total_commission
  commission = product.consignor.try(:COMMISSION)
  commission ? (PRICE * commission) : 0
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try other solutions tho

Comment: I don't think you need to use `self` if you are just reading the attribute

Comment: If I use your solution as it is it returns uninitialized constant Stockdiary::PRICE